# Calling apex:actionFunction on apex:commandButton's onclick event

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, commandbutton

Can we call `apex:actionFunction` on `apex:commandButton`'s onclick event?

Actually i am trying to do this but controller's method is not being called.

i am doing something like below -

```
 <apex:commandButton title="Apply and Continue" value="Apply and
 Continue" onclick="setState()"/>
```

Action function is declared like below -

> ```
> <apex:actionFunction id="setState" action="{!checkClick}" name="setState" >
>       <apex:param name="state" assignTo="{!state}" value="update"/>
> </apex:actionFunction>
> ```

Controller Code -

```
  public PageReference checkClick() {
      system.assert(false, 'In -' + state);
      return null;  
  }
```

controller's `checkClick` is not being called. Page just get refreshed.

Comment: I think this is because the actionFunction expects to get 1 parameter.

Comment: I have tried this as well like setState('update') but result is same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a race condition here - once the onclick handler completes the command button will continue with its normal flow and submit the form.

Thus both the commandbutton and the actionfunction components will both try to submit the form, and as the commmandbutton goes first I'd expect it to win, although its not an exact science.

If you want to use an actionfunction in this way, you have to stop the normal behavior of the commandbutton. One way to do this is to return false from the onclick handler:

```
<apex:commandButton title="Apply and Continue" value="Apply and Continue" 
                    onclick="setState(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: ok got your point but why does code starts working if i put rerender="xyx" in commandbutton? Secondly onclick handler will complete when your actionFuction action is called i believe and after than commandbutton action should called. what do u think?

Comment: Now method is being called but parameter is not being passed. i am getting null in controller –

Comment: Value is being passed on controller if i put rerender="xyx" in actionFuction. Do you know why?

Comment: There is an issue that has been around for years that if you don't have a rerender attribute the parameter doesn't go to the controller, but I thought that was just for command buttons: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002664&language=en_US - it may be that its not working for action functions now.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Secondly onclick handler will complete when your actionFuction action is called i believe and after than commandbutton action should called. what do u think?

Comment: When the actionfunction is called a postback takes place. If you then allow the command button to continue, one of the postbacks will win and the other will be discarded. You should put all of the functionality in one place and just use that postback I would say, otherwise the results will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

When you define parameter to `actionfunction` then action javascript accept it as argument.

```
<apex:page controller="TestActionFunctionWithoutAction">
  <apex:form>

     <apex:commandButton title="Apply and Continue" value="Apply and
         Continue" onclick="setState()" rerender="xyx"/>      
     <apex:actionFunction id="setState" action="{!click}" name="setState" >
      <apex:param name="state" assignTo="{!state}" value="update"/>
     </apex:actionFunction>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public class TestActionFunctionWithoutAction
{
   public pagereference click()
   {
     System.assert(false,'That it!');
     System.debug('------------------------------------- ');
     return ApexPages.currentPage();
   }

   public void abc()
   {
   }
}
```

Result:

> Assertion Failed: That it! Error is in expression '{!click}' in page
>   ashcloud:testactionfunction An unexpected error has occurred. Your
>   development organization has been notified.

Comment: I have tried this as well but result is same.

Comment: @PramodKumar did you add `autocomplete` attribute to check?

Comment: no didn't add that. Let me try with that

Comment: @PramodKumar use actionfunction code I posted in answer.

Comment: getting "test" in alert but server method is not being called

Comment: Check javascript console for any errors

Comment: @PramodKumar oncomplete verifies that action function did his work correctly. Can you post Apex code?

Comment: I have modified question and have added server code as well.

Comment: @PramodKumar also apex commandbutton don't have `action` attribute. It won't post to server without it.

Comment: It would be redundant if i call the same method from actionFunction and action. secondly its not working as well. It is calling only action="" method not actionFunction action method.

Comment: @PramodKumar Try with Sample code. I updated in my answer

Comment: After adding  rerender="xyx" it worked but i didn't get clue why?

Comment: `rerender="xyx"` in your case this prevents viewstate to refresh by command button also you can prevent default behaviour of command button by javascript `return false`. @PramodKumar

Comment: Now method is being called but parameter is not being passed. i am getting null in controller

Comment: Value is being passed on controller if i put rerender="xyx" in actionFuction. Do you know why?