# actionFunction is not getting called in Firefox

Tags: apex, visualforce

I came across a strange issue. My actionFunction is not working in Firefox. But it is working smoothly in IE n Google Chrome.

**VF code:**

```
                 <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="uploadblockid" styleClass="uploadfile_row">
                  <div class="choosefile_part"><apex:inputFile id="inputFileId" fileName="{!strAttachName}" title="Task Attachmnet"  value="{!taskAttachmentBlob}" /></div> 
                  <div class="uploadbtnfile_part">
                      <apex:actionRegion >
                        <apex:commandButton id="uploadfile" value="Upload" onclick="if (!checkSize()) {return false;} else{ disableButton(this);  } " styleClass="upload_btn">
                        <apex:actionFunction name="SubmitUploadOnClick" id="SubmitUploadOnClick" action="{!upload}" /> 
                        </apex:commandButton>
                      </apex:actionRegion>
                  </div>   
                </apex:outputPanel>
```

**JS snippet:**

```
    function checkSize()
    {
        var length = j$("[id$='inputFileId']")[0].files.length;
        alert('length:'+length);

        if(length==0){
            alert('Please select an attachment to upload.');    
            return false;       
        }
        else{
            var size = j$("[id$='inputFileId']")[0].files[0].size;
            if(size<10485760){

                alert('size:'+size);
                return true;
            }
            else{
                alert('Your attachment was not uploaded as attachment upto 10 MB is allowed.');
                //j$("[id$='inputFileId']").focus();
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    function disableButton(ButtonObj)
    {
        //ButtonObj.style.display="none";
        alert('disabling button');
        ButtonObj.disabled="true";
        alert('callling controller...');
        SubmitUploadOnClick();
    }
```

**Apex Controller snippet:**

```
public void upload() {
        System.debug('in upload..!');
}
```

I am not getting, that debug statement in debug logs. 
Did anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Do you see any JS error in firebug?

Comment: nope. there is no bug in console.

Comment: are you getting the alert 'callling controller...'??

Comment: yes. but the system.debug statement is not getting

Comment: You have an `actionFunction` within a `commandButton` - Move the `actionFunction` elsewhere on the form and try having the commandButton's `else` invoke a JS function that does (1) `disableButton()` and (2) invokes  `SubmitUploadOnClick()`

Comment: It is working after changing placement and adding a different form tag to this section.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @crop1645 Could you please tell me, why it was working in Chrome n IE n not working in Firefox, m curious to know about it. Because most of the time IE fails and QUIRK occurs only for UI issues, for functionality I seen this first time.

Answer (score 1):

Your apex:commandButton has no action, which means it's not doing anything different than a normal HTML button.

Try this instead of the apex:commandButton :

```
<input type="button" id="uploadfile" value="Upload" onclick="if (!checkSize()) {return false;} else{ disableButton(this);  } " styleClass="upload_btn">
```

Also, there's no need for the apex:actionFunction to be nested inside the button element.

Edit:

Actually, just return false from your apex:commandButton's onclick.

```
<apex:commandButton id="uploadfile" value="Upload" onclick="if (!checkSize()) {return false;} else{ disableButton(this); return false;  } " styleClass="upload_btn">
```

See [Calling apex:actionFunction on apex:commandButton's onclick event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29400/calling-apexactionfunction-on-apexcommandbuttons-onclick-event) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line -

```
<apex:actionFunction name="SubmitUploadOnClick" id="SubmitUploadOnClick" action="{!upload}" />
```

to

```
<apex:actionFunction name="SubmitUploadOnClick" id="SubmitUploadOnClick" action="{!upload}" rerender="uploadblockid"/>
```

Let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for a try. But still I am getting same problem.