# Javascript not calling apex function

Tags: apex, javascript

I have an actionfunction called 'afterValidation' defined;

```
<apex:actionFunction name="afterValidation" action="{!prohibitedCountryCheck}" />
```

I am calling this function on 'Next' button;

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Next" onclick="showProhibitedCountryAlert(isProhibitedCountrySelected)"/>
```

---

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
        function showProhibitedCountryAlert(isProhibitedCountrySelected) {
            alert('isProhibitedCountrySelected = ' +isProhibitedCountrySelected);
            //alert('countryLookUpInfo = ' +countryLookUpInfo);
            if(isProhibitedCountrySelected) {
                alert('DO NOT create an Account that is located in any of the following countries ');
                afterValidation();
                //alert('After validation invoked');
            } else{afterValidation();}
        }
</script>
```

But strangely, `afterValidation()` function isn't invoked in 'Chrome' though it works fine in IE. Why might that be, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check the console for any error messages?

Comment: There are no error messages in the console.

Answer (score 0):

an apex:commandButton submits the form. This happens in parallel to the call to the onclick function, creating a race condition.
See also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29400/calling-apexactionfunction-on-apexcommandbuttons-onclick-event

if you use <input type="button"> it will most likely work. Interestingly it does not work for me using <button>